# How to say thinking in the past but it's just in a short time?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

A sentence might help to understand my question:

> I ___(*think*) that you were no longer interested in him, but I was wrong.

What tense should I put there?

I'm trying to translate my language into English and this is what Google Translate suggested:

> I used to think that you were no longer interested in him, but I was wrong.

However, I don't think that's appropriate. In my opinion (my understanding), **used to** is used to tell a habitual in the past that I don't do it anymore in the present. And if I'm not mistakenly remember, to talk about an event in a short time in the past we usually use past continuous.

Is it OK if I say:

> I was thinking that you were no longer interested in him, but I was wrong.

Comment: _Used to think_ seems perfectly suitable to me. You had that opinion for a time in the past, but you don't any more because you have learned that it was wrong. Or you could just say _I thought. I was thinking_ is not idiomatic in this context.

Comment: I agree with Kate Bunting. The most common usage would be "I thought you were no longer interested in him, but I was wrong." That sentence indicates past opinion, but doesn't indicate how far in the past. If you want to indicate near past, you might use "I recently thought you were no longer interested in him, but I was wrong."

Comment: A common phrase is, "At first I thought that..." which is used to talk about your first impression before you learned more about the situation.